# Parity node browser not supported in the ethembedded .iso?

Tags: wallets, parity, browsers, embedded

I recently started a node with the parity implementation.  I could easily load the console and wallet in my browser via http://localhost:8080/home/.

Then I downloaded the parity pre-loaded .iso from ethembeded and tried to start a node on my raspberry pi.  For some reason I cannot get http://localhost:8080/home/ to load in my browser. Has anyone else had this experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethembedded [ships an image](http://ethembedded.com/?page_id=102) called `Raspi2-Parity-Homestead-1.0.0-Image`. I'm therefore assuming it comes with parity in version 1.0.0.

The HTTP web interface was added in [parity 1.1.0](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/releases/tag/v1.1.0).

The latest stable release is [parity 1.2.4](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/releases).

Comment: Yes you are correct the image is 1.0.0